# Why in below code return type is class type used for operator overloading?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have been trying to understand operator overloading and did not get the use of return type as class type in the below program:
When I switch "overload" return type with "int" it works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

class overload { 
private: 
    int count; 

public: 
    overload(int i) 
        : count(i) 
    { 
    } 

    overload operator++(int) //why return type is class type when i can use int
    { 
        return (count++); 
    } 
    overload operator++() //why return type is class type when i can use int
    { 
            count = count + 1; 
            return count;        
    } 
    void Display() 
    { 
        cout << "Count: " << count<<endl; 
    } 
}; 
// Driver code 
int main() 
{ 
    overload i(5); 
    overload post(5); 
    overload pre(5); 

    // this calls "function overload operator ++()" function 
    pre = ++i; 
    post = i++; 
    i.Display(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Do you want why is it working/not working, the explanation or you just want the answer to make it work properly?

Comment: It can be `int` but it is normal practice for overloaded operators to behave in a certain way that people will expect (which is returning the same type as the operand, and the right value category for pre-increment).

Answer (score 1):

There are no restrictions on the return type of an overloaded operator. Here it can be `int` as well.
The code you show has the class type as return type to facilitate the other statements in the code as below if ever the constructor of the `overload` class is marked `explicit`;

For example with:

```
explicit overload(int i) 
        : count(i) 
{ 
}
```

and

```
int operator++(int) //return type is  int
{ 
    return (count++); 
} 
int operator++() //return type is int
{ 
     count = count + 1; 
     return count;        
}
```

The following will fail to compile:

```
pre = ++i; //will not work
post = i++; //will not work
```

This is because the implicit copy assignment operator will no longer be viable for conversion from `int` to `const overload`.

See [**Demo**](https://godbolt.org/z/JVxqL7)

Note that the [Canonical implementations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) of the prefix and postfix increment/decrement operators return `overload&` and `overload` respectively.

> Although canonical form of pre-increment/pre-decrement returns a reference, as with any operator overload, ***the return type is user-defined***; for example the overloads of these operators for std::atomic return by value

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the pre/post increment operators is that one works on the object directly (pre-increment: ++foo), and one needs to take a copy of the object and return that (post increment: foo++). A slightly more verbose way of writing this would be:

```
// return a new object that represents the old value
overload operator++(int)
{ 
    overload oldValue(count); // take copy
    count++;                  // increment this object
    return oldValue; 
} 

// increment the count, and return a reference to this object
overload& operator++()
{ 
    ++count;
    return *this;        
}
```

Whilst you *could* return int *(don't do that!)*, it will only lead to confusion. Effectively it would cause a few issues with code such as:

```
overload foo = ++someOtherFoo;
```

Which if you were to return int from ++, would effectively end up calling your constructor function (rather than copy constructor) to construct a new object. i.e.

```
overload foo = overload(++someOtherFoo);
```

That constructor *might* not be available, and so the code would fail.

If you want your object to automatically convert itself to an integer, then the correct way would be to overload the cast operator, e.g.

```
operator int () const
{ 
  return count; 
}
```